# .htaccess php with .gif extension

Tags: php, .htaccess, gif

I know I can write a php script and save it with an image ext. by adding the following to my `.htaccess`

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .gif`

But what if I only want files in a certain directory to be treated as such? How would I do that? I'm thinking about making a a footer for my email account, I would like to gather some basic non-intrusive data with it. Would this even work (assuming the client doesn't have images turned off)?

Comment: My concern is that google - or whoever- will simply copy my image to their own servers like facebook does, but I haven't checked to see if they do yet.

Comment: Google and Facebook most likely will check headers first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Files "/thisdirectory">
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .gif
</Files>
```

See here for Apache 2.4 docs.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html